# How to subtract seconds from current timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I'm trying to create a query which will get the results that were inserted in the last 10 seconds:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE client_id = 1
    AND hash = 'x'
    AND insert_time >= current_timestamp - **10 seconds**
```

I've been searching how to subtract 10 seconds from the current timestamp, but I didn't succeed yet.

Answer (score 8):

Due to [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) you should use `SUBTIME`

```
    ...
    and insert_time >= SUBTIME(current_timestamp,'0 0:0:10.000000');
```

Alternatively you can use `INTERVAL` as following:

```
    ...
    and insert_time >= SUBTIME(current_timestamp, INTERVAL 10 SECOND);
```

---

Notice that due to [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

> When invoked with the INTERVAL form of the second argument, SUBDATE() is a synonym for DATE_SUB().

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(current_timestamp, insert_time)) > 10;
```

Comment: Although this may be logically correct, it's a poor choice because a calculation must be done every row, which will be slow. It's best to calculate a constant value once per query and compare every row to that.

Answer (score 0):

You Want:

```
insert_time >= DATE_SUB(current_timestamp, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
```